# Solving ODE involving an unknown function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u(x), f(x)$ be positive functions supported on $x\in(0,\infty)$. If I have
$$\left(x^2u''(x)-2xu'(x)+2u(x)\right)\left(f(x)+c\right)=x^3u''(x)$$
Given that $u(0)=f(0)=0$ and $c>0$ a constant. Also, $f'(0)=kc,\ k>0.$

Is there a way to solve the ODE with the information above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Guessing that there may be a solution with vanishing second derivative, $u(x) = C_1x$ does work as a solution. Now let's use variation of parameters to find the other linearly independent solution. Guessing $u(x) = xv(x)$ we get

$$x^3v''(x)(f(x)+c) = x^3(2v'(x)+xv''(x)) \implies v'' - \frac{2}{f(x)+c-x}v'=0$$

so we get that

$$v(x) = C_1\int e^{\int \frac{2}{f(x)+c-x}} + C_2$$

but the last constant doesn't matter since it will be absorbed by the other term. Now we have our general solution:

$$u(x) = C_1x + C_2x\int e^{\int \frac{2}{f(x)+c-x}}$$

I'm afraid we can't go any further than that without more information on $f$ or the value of $u$ at another point besides $0$.